# unfamiliar syntax in Haskell / Clash function type signature

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, clash

while trying to understand the usage of the function [`withClockResetEnable`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/clash-prelude-1.8.1/docs/Clash-Prelude.html#v:withClockResetEnable) in [Clash.Prelude](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/clash-prelude-1.8.1/docs/Clash-Prelude.html), I found the signature of this function like this:

```
withClockResetEnable
  :: forall dom r. KnownDomain dom
  => Clock dom
  -> Reset dom
  -> Enable dom
  -> (HiddenClockResetEnable dom => r)
  -> r
```

The thing really cause my confusion is this part

```
  -> (HiddenClockResetEnable dom => r)
```

which has a comment below: `The function with a hidden Clock, hidden Reset, and hidden Enable argument`

My confusion is, my limited knowledge tell me, since there is a `=>`, this line is maybe indicated a type constraint, like the polymorphic type `r` should have an instance of `HiddenClockResetEnable dom`, which still makes no sense to me, and I cannot link this line to the comment at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is using the [`ImplicitParams`](https://ghc.gitlab.haskell.org/ghc/doc/users_guide/exts/implicit_parameters.html)  language option.

[`HiddenClockResetEnable`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/clash-prelude-1.8.1/docs/Clash-Prelude.html#t:HiddenClockResetEnable) is defined as:

```
type HiddenClockResetEnable dom = (HiddenClock dom, HiddenReset dom, HiddenEnable dom)
```

Each of the parts such as [`HiddenClock`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/clash-prelude-1.8.1/docs/Clash-Prelude.html#t:HiddenClock) is defined like this:

```
type HiddenClock dom = (Hidden (HiddenClockName dom) (Clock dom), KnownDomain dom)
```

We have `KnownDomain` in the constraints on `withClockResetEnable`. So what is [`Hidden`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/clash-prelude-1.8.1/docs/Clash-Hidden.html#t:Hidden)?

```
type Hidden (x :: Symbol) a = IP x a
```

The [`IP`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/ghc-prim-0.6.1/docs/GHC-Classes.html#t:IP) class is what the `ImplicitParams` syntax desugars to. So the original signature means:

```
withClockResetEnable
  :: forall dom r. KnownDomain dom
  => Clock dom
  -> Reset dom
  -> Enable dom
  -> ((?clock :: Clock dom, ?reset :: Reset dom, ?enable :: Enable dom) => r)
  -> r
```

In other words, if you call `withClockResetEnable c r e f`, and `f` is some computation that takes these parameters implicitly, then `withClockResetEnable` will call `f` with those arguments for the implicit parameters:

```
let
  ?clock = c
  ?reset = r
  ?enable = e
in f
```